# Regular expression to get first value from comma seperated list of ip addresses

Tags: regex

I want to build a regular expression that will return(match) the first IP address from the given comma separated list of ip addresses.

For e.g, from the below string

```
10.5.19.25, 25.85.45.73, 65.89.59.68
```

it should return `10.5.19.25`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use this regex,

```
^(\d+\.){3}\d+
```

This will give only first IP address among the list.

Explanation:

```
^ matches start of line
(\d+\.){3} matches digits followed by a dot exactly three times
\d+ matches digits and the match stops here.
```

Demo,

https://regex101.com/r/8rYQlV/1

Comment: Glad to help :) Can you please consider upvoting and/or marking my answer as accepted?

Comment: Somebody looks like very mad at me. Specially targeting my answers and downvoting them without leaving a reason for downvote. Stackoverflow should suspend or put reputation penalty for such users who downvote an answer without leaving a reason, specially for answers that work well and are accepted answers.